# swiftUI ContextMenu без фона

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

я создал свою View и при длительном нажатии на него открывается меню с выбором действий, но при этом вокруг выделеной View остается пространство по углам :[image: видно что углы у view белого цвета, но их не должно быть]
вот код View:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ProjectView: View {
    var name : String
    var img : Image

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top){
            ZStack(alignment : .bottom){
                img
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(16.0)
                    .frame(alignment : .top)

                img
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .blur(radius:2,opaque: true)
                    .mask(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .frame(height: 16.0)
                            .padding(.all,8)
                            .frame(alignment: .bottom)

                        )
                ZStack(alignment : .center){
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .frame(height:16)
                    .padding(.all,8)
                    .foregroundColor(.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.5))

                    Text(name)
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 8.0)

                }
            }
        }
        .shadow(radius: 4)
        .contextMenu{
            Button(action: {

            }) {
                Text("Rename")
            }

            Button(action: {

            }) {
                Text("Clone")
            }

            Button(action: {

            }) {
                Text("Share")
            }

            Button(action: {

            }) {
                Text("Delete")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ну и вопрос: как убрать эти белые углы?

UPD:
вот как выглядит Debug View Hierarchy:

[image]

ссылка на проект:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BPTQ2oJ5WDoy29Q2x_FjK5tmg4pfdRnR?usp=sharing

Comment: Каков исходный размер изображения? И  посмотрите (и при необходимости добавьте сюда) скрин с Debug View Hierarchy

Comment: @schmidt, 400 на 230. Но как это может помочь в вопросе? эта проблема возникает не из за изображения, а из за того что ContextMenu берет квадратную область View вместе с закругленными углами(где по сути ничего не находится)

Comment: а в Debug View Hierarchy как это все выглядит?

Comment: @schmidt9, добавил скрин к вопросу

Comment: Хм тут сложно что-то сказать, попробовал ваш код и углы выглядят нормально, можете залить куда то тестовый проект с проблемной картинкой? Интересно бы было воспроизвести

Comment: @schmidt9, а можете показать как это выглядит у вас?

Comment: В данный момент нет, но там всё ок с углами, правда углы мелькают при анимации и еще ошибки с констрейнтами

Comment: Поэтому лучше всего если вы представите свой тестовый проект с картинкой, указав версию икскода и аппарат, на котором запускали

Comment: @schmidt9, добавил ссылку на проект к вопросу
xcode версии 11.3
пробовал на устройствах iphone 11 pro и iphone 8
но скорее всего проблема на всех устроиствах

Answer (score 1):

Я посмотрел ваш проект, в качестве единственного решения я вижу изменение радиуса закругления изображения, чтобы он был равен закруглению контейнера меню (8 пунктов). Радиус закругления самого меню и его контейнера изменить не удается, хотя на скрине видно, откуда берутся торчащие былые углы (постоянное закругление меню 8 пунктов).

```
img
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
.cornerRadius(8) // << 
.frame(alignment : .top)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это конечно решит проблему, но лишь частично. анимация открытия этого меню все равно будет сопровождаться с углами(т.к. изначально берется квадратная область у View и постепенно закруляются углы, да и менять дизайн тоже не хочется.